# Postgres jsonb contains @> should consider duplicates

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to do "contains all including duplicate elements" in a postgres jsonb array.

I am currently using `@>` which is returning true when the duplicate elements aren't in the original array.

For example, I am looking for an operator where this query returns true:

```
select '[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb @> '[1, 2]';
```

But this query returns false

```
select '[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb @> '[1, 1]';
```

`@>` returns true for both.

Comment: According to rules here [JSONB containment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT) there is not one.

Comment: Do you need it only for flat arrays like in example, or you have more complex structures in mind?

Comment: @qaziqarta It's only for flat arrays like the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no json containment function that tests for containment of elements, respecting the elements' counts at the same time.

You can write such function yourself, e.g.:

```
create or replace function jsonb_full_contain(a jsonb, b jsonb) 
returns boolean language sql as $$ 
select not exists(
  select 1 from (
    select 't1' t, jsonb_array_elements(a) v
    union all
    select 't2', jsonb_array_elements(b) v
  ) tt
  group by v 
  having count(case when t='t1' then 1 end) < count(case when t='t2' then 1 end))
$$;
```

```
select jsonb_full_contain('[1,2,3]'::jsonb, '[1,1]'::jsonb); -- returns false
select jsonb_full_contain('[1,2,3]'::jsonb, '[1]'::jsonb); -- returns true
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hKEXzv1Z)